# Install Ruby 2.2 on Mac OSX Catalina with ruby-install

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, compilation

Here's what I get when I try to install Ruby 2.2:

```
$ ruby-install ruby 2.2.10
# ...
>>> Compiling ruby 2.2.10 ...
    CC = clang
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = clang -dynamic -bundle
    CFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens   -pipe
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -fPIE
    CPPFLAGS = -I/opt/X11/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/gdbm/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19 -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend -Wl,-pie -framework CoreFoundation
    SOLIBS = -lgmp
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.31.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
translating probes probes.d
. ./vm_opts.h
file2lastrev.rb: does not seem to be under a vcs: .
make: [.revision.time] Error 1 (ignored)
./revision.h unchanged
compiling main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling miniprelude.c
compiling array.c
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
compiling compar.c
compiling complex.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling encoding.c
encoding.c:825:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_str_change_terminator_length' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        rb_str_change_terminator_length(obj, oldtermlen, termlen);
        ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [encoding.o] Error 1
!!! Compiling ruby 2.2.10 failed!
```

- OS Version: 10.15.6
- ruby-install version: 0.7.1

Any ideas on how to debug or fix this? I was previously able to install other versions of 2.2 before I upgraded my OS. I'm also able to install later versions like Ruby 2.7 with no problem

Comment: Having the same issue. I have ruby 2.2.4 and MacOS 10.15.5.  I'm running `rvm pkg install openssl`.

Comment: Actually running - `rvm reinstall 2.2.10 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr`

Comment: If you want to sideskirt the issue Travis CI has [a list of ruby binaries](https://rubies.travis-ci.org/) including 2.2.4.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of breaking my head and realizing that the error has to do with the compilation using GCC that is native to macOS, I decided to do a test.

Because older versions of Ruby need instructions that are no longer present in updated make, it is necessary to download an older version of Command Line Tools for Xcode.

First, remove your actual version with:

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Ignore the error about missing git.

Proceed to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and download 11.x version of Command Line Tools for Xcode.

I downloaded version 11.5 and it worked.
My return when running `gcc -v`

```
Configured with: --prefix = / Library / Developer / CommandLineTools / usr --with-gxx-include-dir = / Library / Developer / CommandLineTools / SDKs / MacOSX.sdk / usr / include / c ++ / 4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: / Library / Developer / CommandLineTools / usr / bin
```

To compare, with recent Command Lines, 12.x, you'll see something like:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: Installing the 11.x version of Command Line Tools did not resolve this problem for me. `gcc -v` still displayed output from the 12.x version. However, downloading and installing the _full_ Xcode 11.5 package did resolve the problem. Thanks so much for pointing me in this direction!

Comment: Weird. But I don’t have full Xcode installed. I’ll update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently ignoring the compiler warning is also an option

```
export optflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

For further duscussion see [Problem when installing Ruby 2.2.9 on Mac Big Sur M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65325136/problem-when-installing-ruby-2-2-9-on-mac-big-sur-m1/65340515#65340515)

Comment: This worked for me using rbenv/ruby-build, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this did _not_ work for me when trying to install Ruby 3.0.3 with ruby-install: it did bypass most of the errors, but then at one point the C code tries to reference a struct pointer returned by one of the implicitly declared functions, and since the function's return type has been implicitly assumed to be int… yeah, that's not gonna work. :(

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install that version on Mac 10.15.7 using rvm.

I have openssl@1.1 installed with homebrew. If you run `brew info openssl` what do you see? I would try `brew upgrade openssl` first.

Try running
`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"` with the info brew returns. Then try `rvm install 2.2.10`. If that doesn't work I would try `rvm install 2.2.10 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl --with-openssl-lib=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-openssl-include=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include` just make sure those paths are correct for your system.

You may also need to run

`export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"`

`export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"`

beforehand, which will be supplied by `brew info`.

Comment: Setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` worked for me. Ironically, it seems to have worked because my OpenSSL version (3.0.1) is too new, so the Ruby build just skipped trying to install the openssl extension entirely, saying: "OpenSSL >= 1.0.1, < 3.0.0 or LibreSSL >= 2.5.0 is required." But whatever, at least I have a (mostly) working Ruby now. :D

Answer (score 0):

Adding some extra options here that might help:

We need the right SSL version:

```
$ brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0

$ rvm install 2.2.10 -C --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.0`
```

Answer (score 0):

First, install open-ssl

```
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
```

Then

```
CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.5 --with-openssl-dir='/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to install ruby-2.2.0 in Catalina 10.15.7 and was facing the same issues. But luckily managed to get my work done. Steps are as follows:

1. Installed openssl as a rvm package:

   ```
   $ rvm pkg install openssl
   ```
2. Ignored compiler warnings:

   ```
   $ export optflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
   ```
3. Installed required ruby version (2.2.0 in my case) while providing openssl directory parameter and ignoring rubygems:

   ```
   $ rvm install 2.2.0 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr --rubygems ignore
   ```